# Errors when installing phusion passenger on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, passenger

I'm installing Passenger on Mac OSX (10.9.5) and have been getting errors.  If it matters, Ruby 2.1.2 is installed through rbenv and I have Rails 4.0.0 installed.  Per the 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4' book I'm installing Passenger version 4.0.8.  After typing the command

```
> sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

in Terminal it takes me through some prompts for the installation process and then I get the following error section

```
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:99:2: error: unknown type name 'shared_ptr'
        shared_ptr<SharedData> data;
        ^
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:99:12: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        shared_ptr<SharedData> data;
        ~~~~~~~~~~^
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:126:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'
                        data = make_shared<SharedData>(fd, autoClose);
                        ^
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:145:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                if (data != NULL) {
                    ^~~~
                    StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:145:7: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                if (data != NULL) {
                    ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:146:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                        data->close(checkErrors);
                        ^~~~
                        StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:146:4: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                        data->close(checkErrors);
                        ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:147:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                        data.reset();
                        ^~~~
                        StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:147:4: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                        data.reset();
                        ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:160:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                if (data != NULL) {
                    ^~~~
                    StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:160:7: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                if (data != NULL) {
                    ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:161:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                        int fd = data->fd;
                                 ^~~~
                                 StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:161:13: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                        int fd = data->fd;
                                 ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:162:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                        data->detach();
                        ^~~~
                        StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:162:4: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                        data->detach();
                        ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:163:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                        data.reset();
                        ^~~~
                        StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:163:4: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                        data.reset();
                        ^~~~
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:177:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'; did you mean
      'StaticString::data'?
                if (data == NULL) {
                    ^~~~
                    StaticString::data
ext/common/StaticString.h:161:14: note: 'StaticString::data' declared here
        const char *data() const {
                    ^
In file included from ext/common/Logging.cpp:31:
In file included from ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.h:39:
ext/common/FileDescriptor.h:177:7: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
                if (data == NULL) {
                    ^~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template -fPIC -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<ext/hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -ggdb -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o -c ext/common/Logging.cpp]
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.8/build/cplusplus_support.rb:51:in `run_compiler'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.8/build/cplusplus_support.rb:61:in `compile_cxx'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/common_library.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in define_category_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => apache2 => buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so => buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong

Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:

   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.8/doc/Users guide Apache.html

If that doesn't help, please use our support facilities at:

   https://www.phusionpassenger.com

We'll do our best to help you.
```

I've looked through the documentation like it suggested but can't seem to find what could cause these errors.  I've also looked online with the same result.  Any idea what could cause this?  How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using too outdated version of passenger. Try install it from http://brew.sh/. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#install_osx_homebrew